How to directly calculate $P(A)^{\prime}$?

Six different coloured balls are placed in a box. Kendra and Abdul each select a ball without replacement. What is the probability that Kendra does not select the green ball and Abdul does not select the red ball?

The indirect method of solving the aforementioned question is realizing that the scenario described is one of the thirty possible scenarios; so the answer is $$1-\frac{1}{30}=\frac{29}{30}.$$
For a direct method for solving this question, I thought to multiply the probabilities of Kendra not selecting a green ball and Abdul not selecting a red ball together. After all, $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\times P(B).$ However, when we substitute each probability into the aforementioned equation, the answer is $$\frac{5}{6}\times\frac{4}{5}=\frac{2}{3}.$$ Why isn't the direct method giving us the correct answer?

I think 29/30 is wrong. If "the scenario described" you mention is "Kendra does not select the green ball and Abdul does not select the red ball", there is clearly more than one possibility that this happens since there are 4 colors to choose from aside from red and green.

The scenario I was referring to is Kendra selecting the green ball and Abdul selecting the red ball. We deduct this from the total sample space which leaves us with 29 other possibilities out of 30.



Six different coloured balls are placed in a box. Kendra and Abdul each select a ball without replacement. What is the probability that
Kendra does not select the green ball and Abdul does not select the
red ball?


Without loss of generality, let's assign trials $1$ and $2$ to Kendra and Abdul, respectively.

The indirect method of solving the aforementioned question is
realizing that the scenario described is one of the thirty possible
scenarios; so the answer is $$1-\frac{1}{30}=\frac{29}{30}.$$

There are indeed $30$ possible outcomes, but the described event's complement contains $9$ outcomes, including  $(r, b)$ and $(y, b),$ rather than just one.

For a direct method for solving this question, I thought to multiply
the probabilities of Kendra not selecting a green ball and Abdul not
selecting a red ball together. After all, $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\times P(B).$

This formula doesn't apply, because Kendra selecting Green and Abdul selecting Red are not independent: knowing that Kendra selects Green increases the original $\frac16$ probability of Abdul selecting Red. The correct answer: $$P(R_1)\,P(R_2'\mid R_1)+P(G_1'\cap R_1')\,P(R_2'\mid G_1'\cap R_1')=\frac16\times\frac55+\frac46\times\frac45=\frac{7}{10}.$$

Another approach, which agrees with ryang's answer, is as follows.
Let $X$ be the event that we are interested in, and let $Y$ be the event that neither  the red ball nor the green ball are selected at all.
Now clearly $P(X\mid Y)=1$. Also we have $P(X\mid Y')=1/2$, since (provided at least one ball is red or green) swapping balls will change whether $X$ occurs. So $$P(X)=P(X\mid Y)P(Y)+P(X\mid Y')P(Y')=\frac{P(Y)+1}{2}.$$
Now $P(Y)=\frac 46\times \frac35=\frac4{10}$ giving $P(X)=\frac7{10}$.
